# Using the idea, How Should i use tool.jar with jdk 13

Tags: java, intellij-idea

using the idea with jdk 13,how to use the too.jar?

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        System.out.println("username:" + username + ", password:" + password);
        return null;
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @RequestMapping("/blog")
    public String login(){
        return environment.getProperty("url");
    }

}

Error:(17, 13) java: symbol not found
  Symbol: Class Environment
  Location: class com.example.demo.controller.LoginController
```

Comment: 1) You shouldn't use `tool.jar` with Java 13.  It doesn't exist anymore.  2) This doesn't appear to have anything to do with your actual problem.

Comment: 3) you will need to use IDEA 2019.2 or later to get Java 13 support: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/07/support-for-java-13-preview-features-in-intellij-idea-2019-2/

Comment: thx，I try to update my idea